# Not getting the okta groups in angular oktasignin widget

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, okta

I am trying to get the users group in the okta auth response.
In okta authorization server I set up the claims and scope correctly.
but in angular Okta-sign-in widget I am getting all the users properties except the users **group** . Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, NavigationStart } from "@angular/router";
import { environment } from "@env";

import { OktaAuthService } from "@okta/okta-angular";
import * as OktaSignIn from "@okta/okta-signin-widget";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  signIn;
  widget = new OktaSignIn({
    baseUrl: environment.OKTA_ISSUER,
    authParams: {
      responseType: 'id_token',
      responseMode: 'okta_post_message',
      pkce: true,
      scopes: ['groups']

    },
    logo:'assets/images/resmac_newlogo.png'

  });

  constructor(oktaAuth: OktaAuthService, public router: Router) {
    this.signIn = oktaAuth;
  }

   ngOnInit() {

    this.widget.renderEl(
        {
          el: "#okta-signin-container"
        },
        res => {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(res));
            if (res.status === "SUCCESS") {
              this.signIn.loginRedirect("corporate/home", {
              sessionToken: res.session.token
            });
            // this.widget.hide();
          }
        },
        err => {
          throw err;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

[image: groups]

[image: claims]

[User Details in angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6x8z.png)

Comment: Remove the scopes parameter and you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried the same but still not getting the claims and group in the response . Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you try using `scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']`? That what I used in this example and it shows the groups on the Profile page. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/12/03/angular-okta

Comment: I did look into your sample,  so instead of trying to access the claims in the login page which is not async,  i used async and accessed it in another page after successful login exactly like how you created a profile page .  Now this code gets me the claims and i am able to see the group           'async ngOnInit() {
    const userClaims = await this.oktaAuth.getUser();
    alert(JSON.stringify(userClaims));'

  }'

Comment: @MattRaible Thanks a lot . This issue is resolved . I believe the issue was around async code. and your sample was a great help.